# C++ server crashes with abort() in _UTF8_init() on free()

Tags: c++, c, utf-8, xerces, coredump

I'm having problems with C++ code loaded via dlopen() by a C++ CGI server. After a while, the program crashes unexpectedly, but consistently at memory management function call (such as free(), calloc(), etc.) and produces core dump similar to this:

```
#0  0x0000000806b252dc in kill () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000804a1861e in raise () from /lib/libpthread.so.2
#2  0x0000000806b2416d in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000000806abdb45 in _UTF8_init () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000806abdfcc in _UTF8_init () from /lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x0000000806abeb1d in _UTF8_init () from /lib/libc.so.6
... the rest of the stack
```

Has anyone seen something like this before?

What is _UTF8_init() and why would memory management functions call it?

Comment: Look for problems in your code first. Somewhere in *the rest of the stack* is a call you made. Look at code and usage surrounding that.

Answer (score 3):

That smells like a corrupted heap, likely due to a buffer overrun somewhere in your code.  Try running your program with [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and look for any errors or warnings it emits.

Comment: I have tried Valgrind, but aside from two issues related to Xerces code itself, everything seemed okay.